# Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server after reboot server

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

after reboot server mariadb failed to start and can't get database

So I typed in service mariadb restart; journalctl -xe to see the detailed error:

```
[root@server ~]# service mariadb restart; journalctl -xe
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-1001.slice has finished shutting down.
Sep 10 01:13:27 server.itop.one polkitd[8162]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18782:236011 (system bus name :1.307 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop
Sep 10 01:13:27 server.itop.one systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.31 database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one mysqld[18932]: 2021-09-10  1:13:28 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.31-MariaDB-log) starting as process 18932 ...
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Sep 10 01:13:28 server.itop.one polkitd[8162]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18782:236011 (system bus name :1.307, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US
lines 2203-2225/2225 (END)
```

Comment: what does `journalctl -n 50 -u mariadb.service` show?

Answer (score 0):

I am just facing the same situation.
My conclusion so far is that "systemd" kind of does not start it as a background process and since mysqld intself behaves like a background daemon (like it actually is supposed to) systemd kills it after 900 seconds as it is setup.
Right now I can't say why it does so and neither do I know exactly how to change that yet, but my workaround is to start mysqld as a daemon myself from within a shell so that it doesn't get killed by systemd when it times out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).